# expecting a semi-colon, found 'limit'

Tags: apex, trigger

Any gueses why I am getting error?

```
for(Case cs : cases){
                Integer limit = Integer.valueOf(Label.Old_Request_Limit); // line-28

                if(cs.OldRequest__c == 'Yes' && caseList.size() > limit){
                    cs.addError(Label.Old_Request_Error_Message);
                }   
            }
```

The error coming:

> expecting a semi-colon, found 'limit'

Comment: I can't find any error. Maybe `limit` is a reserved keyword in Apex. Did you try to change the `limit` variable name?

Comment: Right. When I change variable name limit to value. Its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit is an reserved word in salesforce , You can't used as variable name.

Find All reserved Word 
[Reserved Keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm)